# looking for a CRC implementation in Systemverilog

Tags: crc, system-verilog

All,
I'm looking for a class or module that implements a CRC generator (or checker). 
I could create one from scratch, but if there's a ready made one out there that
might be a real time saver :-)

Thanks!
Ran

Comment: have you checked opencores.org?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Example of Ethercat POLYNOM]

Here another example for the CRC calculation. The following examples calculate CRC sequentialy. Therefore, they are slower in comparison with the other solutions that calculate each CRC bit in parallel using XOR. However, I find this solution more "**customizable**" in case you need a different POLYNOM.

```
localparam CRC32POL = 32'hEDB88320; /* Ethernet CRC-32 Polynom, reverse Bits */

function automatic bit[31:0] genCRC32(input bit [7:0] databyte_stream[]);
    int unsigned i, j;
    bit [31:0] crc32_val = 32'hffffffff; // shiftregister,startvalue 
    bit [7:0]  data;

    //The result of the loop generate 32-Bit-mirrowed CRC
    for (i = 0; i < databyte_stream.size; i++)  // Byte-Stream
    begin
        data = databyte_stream[i];
        for (j=0; j < 8; j++) // Bitwise from LSB to MSB
        begin
            if ((crc32_val[0]) != (data[0])) begin
                crc32_val = (crc32_val >> 1) ^ CRC32POL;
            end else begin
                crc32_val >>= 1;
            end
            data >>= 1;
        end
    end
    crc32_val ^= 32'hffffffff; //invert results
    return crc32_val;
endfunction : genCRC32
```

You can have an automatic generation of your CRC from the following website
**http://www.easics.com/services/freesics/crctool.html**

A similar implementation **in C language** using TOPBIT and not LSB bit. from the Altera examples:
https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/others/support/examples/download/crc_accelerator.zip

In german, in the wikipedia. There are examples on how to calculate this.
[https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyklische_Redundanzprüfung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyklische_Redundanzpr%C3%BCfung)

From: https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/intellectual-property/embedded/nios-ii/exm-crc-acceleration.html

An example in systemverilog of a fully configuragle CRC calculator would be

```
localparam CRC_BW        = 8;
localparam CRCXPOLYREV  = 'hE0;    /* CRC-8 Polynom, umgekehrte Bitfolge */
localparam CRCXPOLY     = 'h07;    /* CRC-8 Polynom,  Bitfolge */

function automatic logic[CRC_BW-1:0] generateCRC_X(
     logic [7:0] databyte_stream[],
     input logic reversed_poly=0,
     input logic[CRC_BW-1:0] start_crc_value='1, 
     input logic[CRC_BW-1:0] final_crc_xor_value='0,
     input logic do_end_crc_reversebits=0);
    int unsigned i, j;
    bit [CRC_BW-1:0] crcx_tmp,crcx_val = start_crc_value; /* Schieberegister, Startwert (111...) */
    bit [7:0]  data;


    //Ergebnis der Schleife gibt 8-Bit-gespiegelte CRC
    for (i = 0; i < databyte_stream.size; i++)  // Byte-Stream
    begin
        if (reversed_poly==1) begin
            data = databyte_stream[i];

            for (j=0; j < 8; j++) // from LSB to MSB in one byte!
            begin
                if ((crcx_val[0]) != (data[0]))
                    crcx_val = (crcx_val >> 1) ^ CRCXPOLYREV;
                else
                    crcx_val >>= 1;

                data >>= 1;
            end
        end else begin
            data = databyte_stream[i];
            for (j=0; j < 8; j++) // from LSB to MSB in one byte
            begin
                if ((crcx_val[CRC_BW-1]) != (data[7]))
                    crcx_val = (crcx_val << 1) ^ CRCXPOLY;
                else
                    crcx_val <<= 1;

                data <<= 1;
            end
        end
    end
    crcx_val ^= final_crc_xor_value; //Ergebnis invertieren
    if (do_end_crc_reversebits==1) begin
        for (j=0; j < CRC_BW; j++) // from LSB to MSB in the CRC bitwidth
        begin
            crcx_tmp[CRC_BW-1-j]=crcx_val[j];//reversed
        end
        crcx_val=crcx_tmp;
    end
    return crcx_val;
endfunction : generateCRC_X
```

To test the CRC i recommend
http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html

Answer (score 1):

```
function byte calc_crc(byte unsigned cmd[]);
    bit [7:0] crc, d, c;
    int i;
    crc = 0;

    for (i=0; i<cmd.size(); i++) begin
            d = cmd[i];
            c = crc;
            crc[0] = d[7] ^ d[6] ^ d[0] ^ c[0] ^ c[6] ^ c[7];
            crc[1] = d[6] ^ d[1] ^ d[0] ^ c[0] ^ c[1] ^ c[6];
            crc[2] = d[6] ^ d[2] ^ d[1] ^ d[0] ^ c[0] ^ c[1] ^ c[2] ^ c[6];
            crc[3] = d[7] ^ d[3] ^ d[2] ^ d[1] ^ c[1] ^ c[2] ^ c[3] ^ c[7];
            crc[4] = d[4] ^ d[3] ^ d[2] ^ c[2] ^ c[3] ^ c[4];
            crc[5] = d[5] ^ d[4] ^ d[3] ^ c[3] ^ c[4] ^ c[5];
            crc[6] = d[6] ^ d[5] ^ d[4] ^ c[4] ^ c[5] ^ c[6];
            crc[7] = d[7] ^ d[6] ^ d[5] ^ c[5] ^ c[6] ^ c[7];
    //$display("crc result: %h",crc);
    end
    return crc;
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, Chaggster! brilliant :-)

Comment: @Tudor what if the data on which I have to calculate my CRC is not a multiple of byte but of 9 bits?
ie, `function byte calc_crc(bit[8:0] cmd[]);`

Comment: Where is polynomial for CRC here?

Comment: @KaranShah The polynomial is implicit in the calculations.  It is an 8bit CCITT CRC.  This and the '9-bit' question are related.  It is not clear that you want to perform the CRC over 9bits or have 9 bits of data and want to use an 8-bit CRC.  You need to understand hamming distance and error detection capabilities.  A CRC by itself is no enough; you need to understand the protection it provides.  This answer is given in the spirit of what Verilog CRC would look like.